# Erro em consulta mysql

Tags: mysql, query, phpmyadmin

Estou a horas sem perceber o que há de errado com a minha query. Gostaria que me dessem uma ajuda

```
SELECT 
`recargas`.`valor_recarga` as saldo
FROM `contas_pessoais` 
INNER JOIN `contas` ON `contas`.`titular` = `contas_pessoais`.`titular`
INNER JOIN `recargas` ON `recargas`.`titular` = `contas_pessoais`.`titular`
INNER JOIN `transaccoes` ON `transaccoes`.`transaccao_id` = `transaccao_carregamento`.`transaccao_id`
WHERE `contas`.`titular` = '12';
```

Tenho como retorno este erro:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'transaccao_carregamento.transaccao_id' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: A coluna existe? o nome foi digitado corretamente?

Comment: Na sua consulta não existem nenhuma tabela chamada 'transaccao_carregamento'. Não seria correto usar 'contas_pessoais'?

Comment: Todas as colunas e tabelas referenciadas na query ... existem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tabela transaccao_carregamento não está na sua consulta, você precisa incluí-la em um INNER JOIN.

Comment: Obrigado, @Joel Rodrigues ... Já tinha notado ;)